# "Python" How to split a word of n bytes into n words of two bytes?

Tags: python, split, binary, hex, iterable-unpacking

I've been looking for an answer at my problem, and I can't find anything really similar to my problem.

The thing is that I'm dealing with a value coming from a sensor in binary and I cast it into a hex value. Until that point there is no problem, but after it depends on my sensor but I can have a non define value of bytes.

My idea is to pack those bytes in groups of two bytes.

Here is what i'm doing :

```
val        # This is the value of my sensor in binary

hexval = binascii.b2a_hex(val)        # val casted into an hexadecimal value of n bytes

split = [hexval[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hexval), 2)]        # Here split is an array of n words of two bytes.
```

With this code my problem is that all of my values are mixed, it doesn't seems that I'm packing my values as I should.

If someone can give me an hand with this.

Thanks

Louis

Comment: What should be the output if `val` has an odd number of bits?

Comment: In the idea for my sensors it can't further than 100 bytes, and it will always be a defined value. In an other case I'll change the way I'm doing it, for now it's a 1.0 version.